# How to test new nameserver before to make it live

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, nameserver, domain-name

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Testing nameserver configuration using it](https://serverfault.com/questions/420878/testing-nameserver-configuration-using-it)

I'm thinking of changing from my hosting provider nameservers to Route53 (Amazon's distributed nameserver) for several reasons.

I'm currently setting all records like they are on my current host page (I can see my DNS settings but I cannot change them). Since I'm not used to working with Route53's hosted zones, is there a way I can test the new nameserver resolution settings before updating the domain to point to the new nameserver?

For example, I'm not sure if the last dot in CNAME records is necessary or not...

Answer (score 8):

Use `dig`

```
dig mydomainname.example @mynewnameserver.example
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do that using nslookup, the process is next:

1) Enter `nslookup`

2) Run `server $YourDNSServerName` where $YourDNSServerName is the one of the DNS servers responsible for your zone at Route53 like `nslookup ns-131.awsdns-16.com`

3) From there just enter your records and see the responses.

Comment: Thanks, it works!!
Can you please help me to understand what should i set for these records?
@ IN MX 1 aspmx.l.google.com.
@ IN MX 5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
@ IN MX 5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
@ IN MX 10 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
@ IN MX 10 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
I should leave the domain blank, am I right?

Comment: yes if you're setting MX records for the domain, the domain should be blank.

Comment: Use dig and not nslookup for any serious DNS debugging.  nslookup has many known flaws and has been depreciated.  http://veggiechinese.net./nslookup_sucks.txt

Answer (score 2):

Set up your name server and then configure a test machine to use it for DNS.  I'm not sure what client system you're using, but since I'm on a Windows box, at the moment, a screenshot of where you'd put that new nameserver value on a Windows machine.

[image: DNS settings]

Apply those DNS settings to a number of machines for testing purposes, use as normal, and ensure nothing's broken.

Comment: This will not work. This screen allows you to enter the **recursive** nameservers you want to use. This is certainly not the way to test new **authoritative** nameservers (a lot of things will start to break as you will get DNS replies for only a very small subset of names, or even none at all).

Comment: Why wouldn't that work? The flow goes: 1. Change Windows to use new authoritative nameservers. 2. Test resolution of relevant domain names. 3. Change back to some recursive nameservers. - During number 2 you won't be able to resolve most other domain names so you might want to be aware if you're testing a website that some content such as from a CDN may not load but apart from that it seems fine to me.